# Display webcam snapshots on website

Tags: webcam, html, snapshot

I have a Dlink DCS-942-L webcam that will ftp one snapshot jpeg per hour to my website. It embeds them in a folder by date and then again in subfolders by hour according to time. I would like to display these pictures on a webpage. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: What hypertext pre-processor are you using? PHP? Django?

Comment: I'm not using anything at the moment.  I'm looking for options.

Answer (score 0):

If it was me I will put the images in the same folder than once a day. I will put in the image tags

```
<img alt="A description" src="images/myimage.jpg" width="200px" height="300px" />
```

There is no automatic way to write code to a webpage. If there was a way the website developers and designers will be out of a job. :-)

Someone might have created a C++, C#, or VB program to do this custom job. You might want to put javascript, C#, C++, and VB tags on this message so those groups can read this message